# php preg_grep not working when given reqular expression has a space in between the matching word

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match a word with list of tag names in an array using `preg_grep`

```
$tagOptArray = array("Corporate", "Exporters", "Buyers", "News", "Apparel","Aquarium Fish", "Boat and Ship Building");
$subBlockTag = "Boat";

$tag = preg_grep('/' . $subBlockTag . '[.]*/i', $tagOptArray);

var_dump($tag);
```

this outputs the following result.

```
array(1) { [6]=> string(22) "Boat and Ship Building" }
```

But when `$subBlockTag = "Boat Building";` this returns an empty array which is not expected since it should match with "Boat and Ship Building" in the tags array.

**EDIT**

following are the possible tags that can be assigned for `$subBlockTag`

```
$subBlockTag = "Boat Building";
$subBlockTag = "Ornamental Fish";
$subBlockTag = "Fish";
$subBlockTag = "Fruits and Vegetables";
$subBlockTag = "Diamond and Jewellery";
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to allow any chars in between words separated with spaces (or any non-word chars)? Please clarify.

Comment: Why would it match, you are asking for `Boat Building` followed by anything. `Boat and Ship Building` does obviously not match

Comment: just now i noticed it! i need to know the correct regex for this. when `$subBlockTag` is "Boat" or "Boat Building" it should match the tag "Boat and Ship Building"

Comment: What must be the behaviour for :`building boat`?

Comment: it should also match with "Boat and Ship Building". By using the flag `i` it already achieve this

Comment: I don't talk about case insensitive but about the order of words. Also, if there is "boat" alone in `$tagOptArray`, what must be the result with `boat building` and `building boat`?

Comment: yes in all those scenarios it should match the tag in `$tagOptArray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have regular words separated with spaces in the `$tagOptArray` and you need to match items that contain the words in the same order, you may replace all spaces with `.*` and use your approach:

```
$tagOptArray = array("Corporate", "Exporters", "Buyers", "News", "Apparel","Aquarium Fish", "Boat and Ship Building");
$subBlockTag = "Boat Building";
$tag = preg_grep('/' .  preg_replace("~\s+~", ".*", trim($subBlockTag)) . '/is', $tagOptArray);
print_r($tag);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/NYUeVe).

I suggest to also use `trim($subBlockTag)` to avoid having `.*` at leading/trailing positions, especially in the leading position to avoid performance issues. This might be slow if you have very long texts to handle.

To find a match when all the space separated words are present in the string, you need to construct a regex with positive lookaheads anchored at the start:

```
$tagOptArray = array("Corporate", "Exporters", "Buyers", "News", "Apparel","Aquarium Fish", "Boat and Ship Building");
$subBlockTag = "building boat";
$tag = preg_grep('/^(?=.*' .  implode(")(?=.*", preg_split("~\s+~", trim($subBlockTag))) . ')/is', $tagOptArray);
print_r($tag);
```

See [another PHP demo](https://ideone.com/OfacE5), and here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3nd0bK/1).

Comment: if `$subBlockTag` is `building boat` then that should also match. Also if the `$tagOptArray` has `boat` instead of "Boat and Ship Building" then that should match as well. can we give a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Join the tags with regex OR character `|`

```
$tagOptArray = array("Corporate", "Exporters", "Buyers", "News", "Apparel","Aquarium Fish", "Boat and Ship Building","boat");
$subBlockTag = "Building   Boat";
$tag = preg_grep('/' . preg_replace("~\s+~", "|",$subBlockTag) . '/is', $tagOptArray);
print_r($tag);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [6] => Boat and Ship Building
    [7] => boat
)
```

Comment: your answer resolve the issue when there is only "boat" in the `$tagOptArray`. But it will also match when `$subBlockTag = "Fruits and Vegetables";` please check my edit

Comment: @user27:Because it matches `and`. Don't you want it? How to determine wich word to keep and wich to remove from the search?